Android OS жрет много трафика
Есть телефоны Samsung A23, все рутированы, некоторые из них начали жрать очень много трафика (200-1000гб), обновления отключены, в статистике показывает что трафик жрет Android OS.

Помоги пожалуйста, если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой
